# Kitchen.bat Error downloading mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support/3.2.18.RELEASE_1

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to use Kitchen.bat to try automatically running a job file in PDI. Im having an error that saying "Error downloading mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support/3.2.18.RELEASE_1"

Does someone encounter this kind of error? Below is the full error description

```
Jun 09, 2023 12:09:20 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAcquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
2023/06/09 12:09:20 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Basic
2023/06/09 12:09:20 - Kitchen - Start of run.
org.apache.karaf.features.internal.util.MultiException: Error:
        Error downloading mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support/3.2.18.RELEASE_1
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.<init>(MavenDownloadManager.java:91)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:72)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:457)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:452)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:224)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:401)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.handlePrerequisites(Deployer.java:1124)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:396)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.handlePrerequisites(Deployer.java:1124)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:396)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.handlePrerequisites(Deployer.java:1124)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:396)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1063)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Error downloading mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support/3.2.18.RELEASE_1
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:77)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
                ... 3 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1: [Could not find artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1 in karaf-system (file:C:/Users/jsjavier/Desktop/Pentaho/pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428/data-integration/system/karaf/system/)]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.configureIOException(AetherBasedResolver.java:803)                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:774)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:657)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:598)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:565)
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:52)
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:60)
                ... 6 more
                Suppressed: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1 in karaf-system (file:C:/Users/jsjavier/Desktop/Pentaho/pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428/data-integration/system/karaf/system/)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:368)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:642)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:489)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
                        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767)
                        ... 11 more
        Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413)
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215)
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192)
                at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247)
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767)
                ... 11 more
12:09:22,626 ERROR [BootFeaturesInstaller] Error installing boot features
org.apache.karaf.features.internal.util.MultiException: Error:
        Error downloading mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support/3.2.18.RELEASE_1
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.<init>(MavenDownloadManager.java:91) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:72) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:457) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:224) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:401) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.handlePrerequisites(Deployer.java:1124) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:396) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.handlePrerequisites(Deployer.java:1124) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:396) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.handlePrerequisites(Deployer.java:1124) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:396) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1063) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Error downloading mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support/3.2.18.RELEASE_1
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:77) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1: [Could not find artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1 in karaf-system (file:C:/Users/jsjavier/Desktop/Pentaho/pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428/data-integration/system/karaf/system/)]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.configureIOException(AetherBasedResolver.java:803) ~[?:?]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:774) ~[?:?]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:657) ~[?:?]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:598) ~[?:?]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:565) ~[?:?]
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:52) ~[?:?]
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:60) ~[?:?]
                ... 6 more
                Suppressed: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1 in karaf-system (file:C:/Users/jsjavier/Desktop/Pentaho/pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428/data-integration/system/karaf/system/)
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:48) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:368) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:642) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:489) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:390) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247) ~[?:?]
                        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767) ~[?:?]
                        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:657) ~[?:?]
                        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:598) ~[?:?]
                        at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:565) ~[?:?]
                        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:52) ~[?:?]
                        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:60) ~[?:?]
                        at 



  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
                                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[?:?]
                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
                Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE_1
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413) ~[?:?]
                        at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:215) ~[?:?]
                        at 
    
    shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:192) ~[?:?]
                    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:247) ~[?:?]
                    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:767) ~[?:?]
                    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:657) ~[?:?]
                    at 

org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:598) ~[?:?]
                at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:565) ~[?:?]
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:52) ~[?:?]
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:60) ~[?:?]
                ... 6 more
```